# get Data from a collection in MongoDB using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to get data from Mongo DB by filtering a nested object.

the collection structure is :

```
    { 
   "id":"8820624457",
   "type":"CreateEvent",
   "actor":{ 
      "id":27394937,
      "login":"Johnson0608",
      "display_login":"Johnson0608",
      "gravatar_id":"",
      "url":"https://api.github.com/users/Johnson0608",
      "avatar_url":"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/27394937?"
   },
   "repo":{ 
      "id":163744671,
      "name":"Johnson0608/test",
      "url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Johnson0608/test"
   },
   "payload":{ 
      "ref":"master",
      "ref_type":"branch",
      "master_branch":"master",
      "description":null,
      "pusher_type":"user"
   },
   "public":true,
   "created_at":"2019-01-01T15:00:00Z"
}
```

I am trying to get data by repo id.
my code is :

```
collection.find({'repo.id':id}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    console.log(id);
  assert.equal(err, null);
  console.log("Found the following records");
  console.log(docs);
  res.status(200).json({docs});
  callback(docs);
});
```

but I am getting empty array, would be grateful is someone can point me to the right direction

Comment: What is the value of `id` variable ?

Comment: @mickl id is dynamic I get it from a parmeter const id = req.params.repoId;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB compares **types** before values. If your `id` comes from `req.params` it's probably passed as string while `repo.id` seems to be a number. Try to convert your value to number:

```
const id = +req.params.repoId
```